# authentication error ubuntu software center 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04

Unable to install or uninstall apps in the Ubuntu software center. I get an authentication error, and then a popup says I cannot do this operation since I don't have permission. (Yet i'm administrator.) I do not know what to do. If anyone could please tell me, how can I fix this? (Please explain, i'm still a bit new to Ubuntu. Only starting to figure out new things at a slow pace)
Running: Ubuntu 16.04 LTS
Toshiba Chromebook 2
Dual-boot (Crouton)

Comment: Have you tried using `sudo apt install` instead? Crouton is always a mess, but it's such fun.

Comment: [This page](https://help.ubuntu.com/17.04/ubuntu-help/addremove-install.html) might be helpful.

Comment: I'm having the same issue running 16.04 with Crouton. I've tried installing and then running the gnome policykit  with `/usr/lib/policykit-1-gnome/polkit-gnome-authentication-agent-1`, but I get a warning 'Unable to determine the session we are in'. The policykit is running after the warning, but it doesn't resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same thing, just go into the terminal and run `sudo su`. Then, enter the software center with `software-center`. This worked for me on 14.04, and it should work for you, good luck, fellow Chromebook Linux user!

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve this problem using gksudo. 
First try in bash

`gksudo software-center`

It should ask for a password.
If this works edit ubuntu-software-center

`gksudo gedit /usr/share/applications/ubuntu-software-center.desktop`

and edit

`Exec=/usr/bin/software-center %u`

to

`Exec=gksudo /usr/bin/software-center %u`

This made my toolbar icon work.

This also works for Synaptic package manager.